# I have 4 values obtained from a form, I would like to paste these values into a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have these four values obtained from a userform.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").value = TextBox1.Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").value = ListBox1.Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").value = TextBox2.Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").value = ListBoxw.Value

End with
```

But I want to paste in the next available row instead of just replacing the data in row 2. How can I make it dynamic like that? Do I need to count the number of items already there? So if the user opens the form again, the previously entered data is still there and we just add on. Also, how could I put the current date as the default value in TextBox1?

Comment: "These values" look to be obtained from the worksheet "Sheet1"... The  `Width ... End Width` does not have any meaning in your code. It is there for nothing. Which "next row" are you talking about? You took them from the row 2 and do you like to paste them in the same column but in row 3? You want to count the items "already there"... Where "there"?  When you say "default date" do you mean to make it show the current date when the form is loaded? I am afraid it is very difficult to understand something from your post...

Comment: now the values are obtained from the objects in the userform, so with this worksheet i would like to fill rows with data put into the userform. If i put values in all the userform objects, those values should be put into row 2 under my column headings. If I open the userform again and do the same thing, these new values go into row 3. data is never deleted from a row, it only builds on. And yes i would like to show the current date when the form is initialized

Answer (score 0):

In order to paste the values to the last empty row, use the next code:

```
Sub PasteBelowTheLastRow()
  Dim lastEmptyRow As Long, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastEmptyRow = sh.Range("A:A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     With sh
        .Range("A" & lastEmptyRow).value = TextBox1.value
        .Range("B" & lastEmptyRow).value = ListBox1.value
        .Range("C" & lastEmptyRow).value = TextBox2.value
        .Range("D" & lastEmptyRow).value = ListBox2.value
     End With
End Sub
```

In order to automatically set the current data in TextBox1 you must have the next code in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1.value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't that solve your problem, like I understood it? When somebody spends some time in order to help you, it is at least polite to say something. It works, it does not work, what were your expectations and so on...

Comment: Sorry, I took a break from working on this application. I appreciate your help, it does work. Thank you FaneDuru

Comment: @riddlemethisagain: Welcome! But, in such a case, a vote on the answer up arrow will not kill anybody... :-)